# Ubuntu, can't use @

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I got an problem with my Ubuntu 12.04, ran in a VirtualBox on Windows 7.
Like the title already said I can't use `@`. This one is just copy 'n paste. The problem also concerns the pipe and tilde, I can't use any of these three. My keyboard is a german 104 keys generic keyboard.

I already tried to fix this in the settings, which are provided by Ubuntu. It didn't work for me. I tried to go with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` aswell, I gave every option I could use a try, but it didn't work at all. Creating an `xorg.conf` didn't solve the problem either.

The only positive thing is that I can use nearly every special character in the console, but not in the browser or in any other application.
If you should need any additional information to help me, I will provide it as soon as I can get my hands on it!

Content of `setxkbmap -v -query`:

```
 Trying to build keymaps using the following components:
 keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
 types:      complete
 compat:     complete
 symbols:    pc+de+inet(evdev)
 geometry:   pc(pc104)
 rules:      evdev
 model:      pc104
 layout:     de
```

Conten of `locale`:

```
 LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE=de_DE
 LC_TYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
 LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What keyboard layout is this? Where should the @ be?

Comment: You can use this screen keyboard in such emergencies: `xkeycaps` - it looks old, because it is. And it is still in the default packages, so available everywhere (did not test).

Comment: @Tim it should be `AltGr+Q` (`AltGr` or Right `Alt`).

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I will try this solution later on. The @ is on "Q".

Comment: Olease edit the answer to add the output of this command: `setxkbmap -v -query`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I added the content of `setxkbmap -v -query`. Also, `xkeymaps` didn't work for me. It doesn't have the choices I need for a 104 keys keyboard.

Comment: Did you mean `xkeycaps` (not -maps), right? Interesting... Maybe there is just some basic keyboard related language /i18n X package missing? I can choose the keyboard `PC` `104 key, wide del short enter` `Xfree86;US`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Yes, I meant `xkeycaps`. I can also choose `PC 104 key, wide del, short enter`, but it isn't the keyboard I use. I have a big enter, and a wide del key. The layouts don't match my keyboard too, I use a EU layout, not a US layout. The live keyboard doesn't work either, if I press `alt gr`, it's showing I would press `ctrl` and the `enter` on the num block side...

Comment: Is it German? I'm German, but started to use US keyboards a year ago - so my configuration is strange anyway, not a good example I can show.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It is, I already wrote it above.

Comment: I think the keyboard model may be almost ok, but the options for the modifiers need to implement hat strange european half modifier layer thing - What we just cal "AltGr" ;)

Comment: By the way, can you add the output of `locale`? If there is something strange, that could mess it up, I thing...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Neither I have any `locale` output I know about, nor I understand that modifier thing... :/

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Added the content of `locale`, still, I don't get the modifier thing.

Comment: `locale` looks good. I can show output of `setxkbmap` on a netbook with German keyboard and German language settings. Formating will break... I tell you just the difference to your output in the question: `symbols:    pc+de(nodeadkeys)+inet(evdev)`, `model:      pc105`, `geometry:   pc(pc105)`, `model:      pc105`,  `variant:    nodeadkeys`. In summary, that seems to differ only in using a 105 key keyboard, and that I usually add the option `nodeadkeys` - but I add that only because I like it, not for some keyboard related reason. Hmmm...

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I attached a screenshot for you. As you can see my keboard is now like your settings, and you can see that I typed `@` while the terminal still worked. Anyway, after it finished I can just write `q`'s, again. http://www.directupload.net/show_image.php/d/3700/nhbb8fch_png.htm?d=3700&n=nhbb8fch_png.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days I finally resolved my problem. It was solved for me by disabling `auto capture keyboard` in VirtualBox.
In VirtualBox:
File -> Preferences -> Input -> Disable `auto capture keyboard`

Answer (score 0):

Your trick does not work on VB 4.3.14. But the following is working:
Press Ctl + Alt Gr. Then Release Ctl. Now you can use Alt Gr as normal.

The issue is that Alt Gr activates the Ctl key as well. I cannot confirm that it has anything to do with auto capture keyboard.